# UK - WFH from EU country

Tags: employment

I have been wfh part-time and sharing childcare responsibilities since the beginning of lockdown. I am an EU citizen working in the UK and have asked my employer for the possibility to wfh from my home country for a few weeks provided that borders are open and we are not required to go back to the office. Can they legally refuse that?

Comment: It seems likely that the employer could and would refuse: (1) even with WFH your location is important, e.g. if you need to fetch something from the office. (2) Working abroad can have complex effects for the employment relationship, especially regarding worker's rights and taxation. Unless you're being sent for a specific purpose like visiting a client or a conference, that sounds like too much headache for your HR department.